# How to create properties class handler with using default properties

Tags: java, maven, selenium, cucumber, serenity-bdd

phew there are lots of questions from my side these days, but:

I'm looking for the best solution of how to handle properties file when one of them are missing, than use default values. I'm using:

```
serenity-bdd, selenium, java, maven.
```

My solution is:

1. Create Interface with constants
2. Create handler which is going to have at least 3 methods like,
   getDefaultProperties, 
   getCustomProperties 
   and last is method which should return list of properties, but if defaultValue != customValue than override and put to array and return, then I'm going to handle each parameter where I need.

Appreciate for advice,

Thank you.

Comment: Reading your question I thought that you were going property files. But perhaps what you are looking for is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 no not this one, I'm looking for solution, not for how to get parameters or something.